# What is the meaning of the `--` characters in HTTP POST requests?

Tags: forms, http-post

The article [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) in the MDN docs lists the following example of an HTTP POST request, encoded as `multipart/form-data`:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.example
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary="boundary"

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

value1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"; filename="example.txt"

value2
--boundary--
```

This example says `boundary="boundary"`, but part of the boundaries are seemingly also the characters `--` (or `\n--`?), twice in the last separator. The MDN page does not explain these characters. What is the purpose of them?